# VB.net determine if form variable submitted

Tags: vb.net

I have a meeting registration form where a registrant selects the meeting they wish to attend. Once the meeting is selected, it's submitted to the same page so online and in person availability can be determined. In person attendance has a preset capacity as does the zoom meeting account. If a type of attendance is full, they can join a waiting list.

```
How do I say:

If isdbnull(request.form("meeting2")) or request.form("meeting2") <> "" then
   'do nothing
else
'do something
End if
```

What i want to do is to get the code to only execute after the meeting has been selected and submitted, but it's executing and queries are failing because the code doesn't have the id of the meeting because none has been selected and submitted.

I did try page.IsPostBack and my code block never executes.

Comment: Your logic in the pseudo code doesn't make sense to me. You're saying if the value is null or not an empty String. This is, practically speaking, contradictory. What is it, in plain English, that you want to do?

Comment: I'll also question the use of IsDBNull which is not the same as Nothing or a zero length string. What datatype is request.form("meeting2") expected to return? If it's a string then you could use: If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.form("meeting2")) then 'do something.

Comment: what I want to know is if the form has been submitted and the field meeting2 is not null or empty string.